# Undefined columns selected while subsetting airquality data

Tags: r

I want to subset airquality data so that i can get `airquality$temp` when `airquality$Ozone` is equal to 41.
my code is

```
airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, airquality$Temp]
```

`str()` of my data is

```
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
 $ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
 $ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...    
 $ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: `airquality$Temp[which(airquality$Ozone == 41)]`

Comment: welcome to SO. try `airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, "Temp"]` or `airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, ]$Temp`

Comment: or airquality$Temp[airquality$Ozone == 41]

Comment: if you are new to R, you should have a look at the basic principles of subsetting in R. I kindly refer to https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: use just the column you want to select as `character`

```
airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, "Temp"]
```

**Long answer**:

If you subset a `data.frame` using indexes (`[..., ...]`), you have several options.

1. you can use numeric subsetting: You just provide the index number(s) of rows / columns as integer values. e.g.

   ```
   airquality[1,3] # extracting the 1st row of the 3rd column
   ```
2. you can use logical subsetting (as you do in your example): by using logical comparison you can identify rows / columns which to include in the output

   ```
   airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, colnames(airquality) == "Temp"] # double logical subsetting
   ```
3. you can use character subsetting: *only for columns* you can provide the name of the column(s) as a character vector within the `[, ...]`.

   ```
   airquality[, c("Temp", "somethingElse")]
   ```
4. You can use "Dollar" subsetting, if you want to adress only onw column: Here are two examples which will result in the same output. The only difference is whether it is first subsetted by row or column. Note, that if you already selected the column before subsetting the values within the vector `airquality$Temp` (2nd example), **do not** set a comma within the braces, since you only have a 1-dimensional vector left.

   ```
   airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, ]$Temp
   airquality$Temp[airquality$Ozone==41] # both do essentially the same
   ```

What is wrong with

```
airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, airquality$Temp]
```

**?**

In this case you would subset logically by rows, which is absolutely fine. The subsetting by columns on the other hand would be a numeric subsetting by columns since `airquality$Temp` will parse an integer vector into the subsetting of the columns. Hence, you will end up adressing the columns 67, NA, etc. which are not present and contain `NA`. Thus, R returns the error `"undefined columns selected"`

For further introduction into R's subsetting, have a look at
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

You want the name of the column, not the actual values of the column for the second argument of your subset.

i.e. `airquality[airquality$Ozone==41, "Temp"]`

Also, you've got some NA's in your data, which I presume you want to filter, so you're probably looking for something more like:

`airquality[airquality$Ozone==41 & !is.na(airquality$Ozone), "Temp"]`